# Using SharedPreferences with more activities

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I would like to save a given that then has to be shared between the main and secondary activity. I can not understand why my app does not work.

This is the Second activity:

```
switch (find)
{
case 0:
    lunedi1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green)); 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    pref=0;
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("pref", pref);
    editor.commit();

    break;
```

And this is the MainActivity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int pref=100;
// Leggiamo l'informazione associata alla proprieta TEXT_DATA
int dato = prefs.getInt("pref", pref);
// Lo impostiamo alla TextView
if(pref==0)
{
    lunedi1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green)); 
}
lunedi1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
@Override  
public void onClick(View v) {  
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 
int a=0;
final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
intent.putExtra("info1", info1);
intent.putExtra("a", a);
intent.putExtra("id",id);
startActivity(intent); 
}
```

in this way it should pass the data, and then the background should turn green but this does not happen.

Comment: You have "This is the Second activity:" and "And this is the second activity:" one of those is a typo, I'm assuming?

Comment: Now is correct and edit

Comment: You are setting the pref in `MainActivity` and want to change the background color of a `TextView` in `SecondActivity` from `MainActivity`. I'm still confused.

Comment: why? is it not possible?

Comment: No, you have to set it in the `Activity` where the `TextView` is displayed.

Comment: TextView is in MainActivity

Comment: but before I change the background to receive the data

Comment: Ok, have you tried my answer yet? What you have doesn't make sense

Comment: What do you mean? For the reason I stated in my answer.

Comment: I do not understand. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare and initialize a new variable `pref` here

```
int pref=100;
```

so here

```
if(pref==0)
```

`pref == 100` not 0

Not positive but I think you mean

```
if(dato == 0)
```

Comment: ok thanks. but it is correct that it is now equal to zero even before launching the second activity?

Comment: It looks correct to me but you will have to run it and see

Comment: how is it possible to receive data without launching the activity?

Comment: It's not. I assumed you used an `Intent` somewhere to launch the other `Activity`. That's the only way

Comment: yes, but the intent is after the pressure of a TextView

Comment: " pressure of a TextView" I don't understand this. Maybe you should update your post and make it a little more clear what's going on. I understood it to be that you set a pref value --> go to another `Activity` --> set the background of a `TextView` in the receiving `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

For storing data using `SharedPreferences`:

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

  editor.putString("Tag","value");
  editor.commit();
```

For retrieving data from `SharedPreferences`:

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  String name = preferences.getString("Tag","");
```